# How do I install a window screen that must go in from the outside and does not have tabs, springs, pins, or any flex?

Tags: windows, screens

The house that I moved into had all of the screens removed from the basement windows and left laying near each window (so I'm pretty confident they came with the windows which were installed in 2006). The screens don't have any tabs, springs, pins, or any flex to the frame to shove it up or push down into the casing and just bend it in. Another odd thing is that they appear to require installation from the outside. I've cleaned the frames and the window casing that it is installed into, but I just can't get that last quarter inch needed to get the screen in! Any tips?

Comment: It would help to have a picture of the screen and the window (inside and outside).

Comment: Some frames have one side that can be pushed in.

Comment: Voting to close. OP hasn't been back.

Comment: Was anything broken off them?

Answer (score 2):

They don't all use springs or clips. On many (especially older aluminum and steel frame) windows the channel is deeper on the top and one side. This allows the screen frame to insert, then drop and/or be pulled into the shallower channel whilst still being (half) held in the deeper channel opposite. Usually this type has a plastic "pull-tab" that is held in by the rubber spline, to help the user insert and remove it. It is common to see these tabs break off over time.

**None** are made to have the screen frame bent for insertion.

Comment: usually theres a leaf-spring stop then from drifting sideways after install.